# Does a GCHandle of normal type need to be freed?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, clr, marshalling

MSDN says that

> You can also use GCHandle to create a pinned object that returns a
>   memory address to prevent the garbage collector from moving the object
>   in memory.
>
> When the handle goes out of scope you must explicitly release it by
>   calling the Free method; otherwise, memory leaks may occur. When you
>   free a pinned handle, the associated object will be unpinned and will
>   become eligible for garbage collection, if there are no other
>   references to it.

So if an unpinned a.k.a normal GCHandle was created to a managed class object called fooObj,

```
GCHandle gch = GCHandle::Alloc(fooObj, GCHandleType::Normal);
```

does it need to be freed with Free()?

```
gch.Free();
```

Or does GC release it when it's not required?

The reason I don't want to free it is because in the following code, I need paramsArgVPtr and gch1 to remain referring to the fooObj object even after additional GCHandles like gch2 are allocated and freed. But it seems like once gch2 is freed, the associated object is unpinned despite gch1 still referring to it. Either way gch1 looses access to the object.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

ref class Foo // Required to be a managed ref class
{
private:
    int a = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Foo ^ fooObj = gcnew Foo();

    // Get a void pointer that can access the object
    GCHandle gch1 = GCHandle::Alloc(fooObj, GCHandleType::Normal);
    void * paramsArgVPtr = GCHandle::ToIntPtr(gch1).ToPointer();

    // This would happen in an external non-member function that accepts a void * argument paramsArgVPtr
    // But I'm putting it here for a minimal example.
    GCHandle gch2 = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr(paramsArgVPtr));
    Foo ^ fooObjCopy = safe_cast<Foo ^>(gch2.Target);
    gch2.Free();

    // Check to see if the object is still accessible through gch1
    if (gch1.Target == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "gch1 points to a null pointer after freeing gch2" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "gch1 can still access the object after freeing gch2" << endl;
    }

    gch1.Free();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you created only one handle.  Just one Alloc() call.  gch2 is merely a copy of gch1, both refer to the same underlying CLR handle.  So after Free() the handle no longer exists and the object is eligible to be collected.  Do note that you did not pin anything.

Comment: @HansPassant okay. I cannot make it a pinned handle because the object contains "non-primitive or non-blittable data". But that is okay, because even if the GC moves the object in memory, gch1, paramsArgVPtr and gch2 would all point to the updated address, right?

Comment: @HansPassant Seems like my actual code works fine if I only free that handle set with GCHandle::Alloc() when I am done with it. In the example code above that would be gch1. So if you want to submit your comment as an answer, I can accept that for now. If you have a reference to an MSDN page or something that states the same please include that as well. Thank you so much!